# Partial lighting on a single downstairs lighting circuit

Tags: lighting

In my house I have lights working in one room and outside the house on a single ring lighting circuit.  The room that has the lights are recessed lighting working off 24v converters (I am willing to remove and replace for 240v).  I am using a Fluke T110 to measure all voltage and continuity.  Measurement from the main fuse to the first junction box measures 240v.  When I measure across the 2 way hall lighting switch on the same circuit I am only getting 24v.  I have tested all roses and switches and am not getting any breaks in continuity however I am not getting any voltage other than the mentioned 24v across the hallway switches and the junction box that feeds the hall lighting.  One of the odd things is that the lighting went off (never tripped) and came back on again several hours later only to go off again when the upstairs 2 way switch was switched off. Any help or ideas would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: An electrical diagram of what you are observing would help.

Comment: Maybe the 24V transformer is failing.

Comment: Hi guys.  Thank you for the replies.  I have solved the problem and am sending this reply in case it helps someone:  

The transformer was a red herring.  I found this out once I had cut sections out of the ceiling (after taking up floor boards I found a suspended ceiling on top of another!!!).  The low voltage lighting was just a spur as was the outside light (I couldn't see this till after I cut into the ceiling).

After tracing another wire from the junction box I had to remove sections of the kitchen ceiling ... under one section was another junction box which had a loose wire.